# Nuxt routing multiple levels

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

Could somebody explain how to add a multi levels (children) path using nuxt. The structure of my project is:

```
├root
│  ├── events
│      ├── _id.vue
│      ├── cateogries
│          └── _id.vue
```

Basically my links are like this:

```
http://localhost/events
```

Will display a list of events

```
http://localhost/events/{id}
```

Will display the event information plus some categories

```
http://localhost/events/{id}/category/{id}
```

Will display the event category information

I've tried doing the structure of the folders and subfolders and is not working.
I've tried to use inside _id.vue from events `<nuxt-child/>` and is not working.

Does anyone has any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, not duplicate id param, use other name.

you can use such a structure:

```
├pages
│  ├── events
│      ├── _eid
│          ├── category
|             |__ index.vue
│             └── _id.vue
```

_id.vue for http://localhost:3000/events/2/category/5

```
<template>
    <div>
    {{ $route.params }} //{ "eid": "2", "id": "5" }

    Hello from _id
    </div>    
</template>
```

For each level add index.vue or a dynamic "_".

Also be consistent in names (category or categories)

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to do it and you answer is the correct way to do it.

P.S. The category/categories was a typo :) - when I type slower than I think :p

Comment: Using eid (or aid, bid, cid..., etc) I missed that in the docs, thank you.

Comment: how to solve if need a route like ->> events/{eventId}/{categoryId} how to handle on file paths nuxt?